# How to reduce flicker in terminal re-drawing?

Tags: rust

I have a program that displays the state of some commands ran in parallel

```sh
fmt    ✔
clippy cargo clippy --tests --color always ... 
tests  cargo test --color always ..
```

The program is my first one that relies on multi-threading, and I have some threads running those programs as soon as they are "available", and I have one thread (the main one) dedicated to waiting for new results (which are pretty rare, given that jobs tend to run for at leat a few seconds, and there a relatively few jobs, 10 in parallel at most) and deleting & reprinting in a loop the state of things.

In this part of the software, I don't print the output of the commands, just the commands being ran and some ascii spinner.

I don't know how these things should be done, so I managed to limit redraws to at least 40ms :

```rust
const AWAIT_TIME: Duration = std::time::Duration::from_millis(40);
```

```rust
fn delay(&mut self) -> usize {
    let time_for = AWAIT_TIME
        - SystemTime::now()
            .duration_since(self.last_occurence)
            .unwrap();
    let millis: usize = std::cmp::max(time_for.as_millis() as usize, 0);
    if millis != 0 {
        sleep(time_for);
    }
    self.last_occurence = SystemTime::now();
    millis
}
```

```rust
while let Some(progress) = read(&rx) { ... }    
job_display.refresh(&tracker, delay);
delay = job_starter.delay();
```

So I end up tracking the number of lines and chars written and delete them all :

```rust
struct TermWrapper {
    term: Box<StdoutTerminal>,
    written_lines: u16,
    written_chars: usize,
}

...

pub fn clear(&mut self) {
    (0..self.written_lines as usize).for_each(|_| {
        self.term.cursor_up().unwrap();
        self.term.carriage_return().unwrap();
        self.term.delete_line().unwrap();
    });
    self.written_lines = 0;
    self.written_chars = 0;
}
```

It works, but it tends to flicker, especially in embedded terminals.

My next idea is to store the hash of printed string and skip the redraw if I can.

Are there some known patterns I can apply to get some nicer output ?

What are the common strategies I can use ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum requirement to guarantee no flicker when updating a terminal is: **don't send one thing and then overwrite it with something else** (within a single 'frame' of drawing). In the case of clearing, we can restate that rule more specifically: **don't clear the regions that you're going to put text in.** Instead, clear only regions that you know you *aren't* putting text in (in case there is previous text there).

The conventional terminal command set contains a very useful tool for this: the “clear to end of line” command. The way you can use it is:

1. Move the cursor to the beginning of a line you want to replace the text in.
2. Write the text, *without any newline or CRLF at the end*
3. Write “clear to end of line”. (In `crossterm`, that's `ClearType::UntilNewLine`.)

After sending the clear command, the rest of the line is cleared (just as if you had happened to write the exact number of spaces to completely fill the line). In this way, you need to keep track of which lines you're writing on, but you don't need to keep track of the exact *width* of each string you wrote.

---

The next step beyond this, useful for arbitrary 2D screen layouts, is to remember what text has previously been sent to the terminal, and only send what needs to be changed — in Rust, the [`ratatui`](https://docs.rs/ratatui/) library provides this, and you can also find bindings to the well-known C library `curses` for the same purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider, is try to minimize the count of write outs, and try to write(syscall) the entire update sequence, including cursor positioning and drawing, in one single write().

A real world example is lldb. When you ^?(DEL) in it to delete one char, it not only does unnecessary cursor positions and redraws, but also most importantly flushes output on **every byte** of the first few escape sequences used to do the delete. While in GNU Bash it is just `^H^[[K` in one single write!

Another example is that in GNU Bash, when you delete char at the start of next line, it does a lot of `^[C` s to move the cursor, but it does this in one single write out so you don't notice any flicker even via a bad high latency ssh connection.